# How to receive open cv imge in android phone

Tags: android, c++, opencv, image-processing, imageview

I want to send a photo in open cv saved in cv::Mat object to android phone and I want to show it in an ImageView on android side
I succeed to send the photo data and I received them in an array of integers (int[]) on android
But my problem How to make bitmap from them to show as I don't know the construction of photo in android and its relation with open cv Mat;

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the Mat into an Android Bitmap (this is code for OpenCV's Android interface):

```
try {
    Utils.matToBitmap(mat, bitmap);
} catch (Exception e) {
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
}
```

Then, set the Bitmap as the content of an ImageView (which you've defined in an XML layout file):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

If you're using OpenCV's C++ interface with the Native Development Kit, it's probably best to do the first step in C++ and return the bitmap from the C++ method, then do the second step in Java as before.